# Using more arraylists in one ViewBag

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I want to have cards created from values from arraylists.

My view is:

```
    @foreach (string s in ViewBag.Information)
{
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">@s</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

And I have three Araylists:

```
        ArrayList Name = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList Author = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList Date = new ArrayList();
```

It would by great if I could use it like this

```
    @foreach (string s in ViewBag.Information)
{
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">@Information.Name</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">@Information.Author</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">@Information.Date</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

Or it could work with this, then I can use `@ViewBag.Address.Name`

```
            ViewBag.Address = new Student.Models.Student()
            {
                Name = "Nel",
                City = "USA",

            };
```

But I didn't find the way how I can work with that using arraylists.

Comment: Create a class book with Name, Author and Date property. Create objects of it and assign property values and add to array list. Assign array list to ViewBag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new class and make use `List<T>` and add the relevant data to it, so something like:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Author { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your `ViewModel` you will have:

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public List<Book> Book { get; set; }
}
```

For ease, I have just added the data in the controller action as:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SampleViewModel();
        
        model.Book = new List<Book>
        {
            new Book { Name = "First Book", Author = "Author One", Date = DateTime.Now },
            new Book { Name = "Second Book", Author = "Author Two", Date = DateTime.Now }
        };
        
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Finally in the view you can loop over the result as:

```
 @foreach (var books in Model.Book)
 {
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item">@books.Name</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">@books.Author</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">@books.Date</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
}
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9pmAN6)

**Update**: You won't be able to use all 3 `ArraList` in one `ViewBag`. I suggest you create a view model to hold 3 different props for the `ArrayList`. Assuming all the `ArrayList` have the same number of items in them, you can do the following in your view:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Name.Count; i++)
{
   <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">Model.Name[i]</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Model.Author[i]</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">Model.Date[i]</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I just struggle with new Book { Name = Name , Author = Author, Date = Date }, I can't use foreach, so I don't know how to use arraylists there.

Comment: @Nelaach With the example I've provide, you don't have to use `ArrayList`. Is using `ArrayList` a must for you?